# PTT For Radio Using RasPI Using GPIO to Join two wires together

Tags: gpio

Basically, Can I use the GPIO pins to short/join to wires together then disconnect.

For my radio I have a PTT wire which needs to be grounded on the ground wire to key up.

Do I need a breakoutboard?
What GPIO pins can I use?

There is no electrical current on these wires at all.. its just joining two wires together via gpio using a script

Thanks
Sonic

Answer (score 1):

Basically No.

There must be some "current" on the wires or it would not work.

Connecting GPIO to an unknown foreign circuit risks damaging the Pi and/or the other device.

You could try using a FET as in http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits but the only safe method is to use a relay or optoisolator.